# Span element is disappearing after intitial loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am populating some data from a webservice in a span element. The data which I am getting from the webservices is first adding in a table and then adding that table in the Span element. The table is adding initially in the Span element but after loading it disappeared certainly.In the code snippet I am giving below it is the Span element is giving desired outcome till 'second alert' but after that it is getting disappeared.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: GetAStudent + "(" + nextStudentID + ")",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (student) {
        jPendingStudent = student;
        nextStudentID++;
        //debugger;
        var table = makeTable(student);

        $("#spanStudentList").html("").append(table);
        alert("span 1 created");
        //$("#divNewStudent").css("visibility", "visible");

        //$("#divNewStudent").visible();
        $("#divNewStudent").show();
        alert("span2 created");
        //return false;

    },
```

Comment: Add your html to the qustion.

Comment: Can you provide your html?

Comment: Table inside a Span element is invalid HTML. Can you use Div instead of Span?